# Show price in Stripe::Product.list in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, stripe-payments

I am creating a list of products and skus in Stripe with this format:

- Star Wars T-Shirt (Product)

  - S (Sku)
  - M (Sku)
  - L (Sku)
- Marvel T-Shirt (Product)

  - S (Sku)
  - M (Sku)
  - L (Sku)
- Etc.

I can fill the prices in the skus but I would like to show the price when I call the list of products in Rails.

Any Help?

Answer (score 1):

SKUs are linked to products through the `product` key.

You could retrieve the Products your are looking for and then get all the SKUs linked to those products using

```
Stripe::SKU.list(product: insert_product_id_here)
```

However this can be quite heavy if you have lots of products, since you'll make an API call to retrieve the SKUs for each and everyone of them. For better performance I'd create a record in DB each time I create a SKU for a product to leverage ActiveRecord relations and performance. If your are creating your SKUs from the backend, you can do it at the same time, if your creating your SKUs through the Stripe Dashboard, you can listen to the `sku.created` Webhook event to create it then.